# How to change network configurations in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

Is it possible to change programmatically (C++) on linux the following network configurations:

- Hostname
- DNS
- Network Interface
- Network Protocol
- Network Default Gateway

May be exists any libraries or default C++ functions/classes?

Or I should change this configuration by hand?

Comment: Do you mean permanently or just until the next reboot / interface cycle?

Comment: @cdhowie, thank you for your comment. I need change configuration permanently.

Comment: In that case I don't think there is a consistent API you can use across all flavors of Linux. Lots of flavors use `/etc/network/interfaces` for example to store interface (including default gateway) config information but this is not guaranteed. I don't know of any API that exists to manipulate this file on flavors where it is used.

Comment: I agree with @cdhowie. This is not a C++ related question but distribution specific. You need to check you docs of your linux distribution and edit network files and restart network process. Good luck